# set text size with data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, text-size

I want to set the text size of the text view based on the the number of a characters in the text. So i have a function like getTitleTextSize(). How can this be used with data binding to set the text size

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable in xml (something like that)

```
<data xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <variable
        name="variable"
        type="way.to.your.class" />
</data>
```

and then just write in your TextView xml definition

```
android:textSize="@{variable::getTitleTextSize}"
```

Comment: the problem is how do u specify the unit. i want to set it in pt , like 30pt

Comment: In that case, you could create [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter) and then use [setTextSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%20float))  method